# SQL Server stored procedure for inserting multiple rows in one table and single row in other table 

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am in need of a stored procedure for sales transaction. In a single SP I need to store `CustomerID` in one table and list of products purchased (multiple rows) in another table.

Can any one give me an best example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Show us** what you have already..... what have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is **NOT** a *gimme ze codez* kinda site - we can help with specific questions, but we don't just write the whole code for you...

Comment: I understand that I need how to get input parameter for a SP to insert 1 record(CustomerID) in one table and 30 records of (ProductName,Quantity) in another table

Answer (score 2):

> Table-Valued Parameters is a new feature introduced in SQL SERVER 2008. In earlier versions of SQL SERVER it is not possible to pass a table variable in stored procedure as a parameter, but now in SQL SERVER 2008 we can use Table-Valued Parameter to send multiple rows of data to a stored procedure or a function without creating a temporary table or passing so many parameters.

You can read about it [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)

for more information about using it with ado 
check this great article

[SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven!](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)

Answer (score 0):

well in the stored procedure you can use any many insert commands as you want in any table you want, as your question is not clear enough that i write the exact stored procedure you want, I'm writing an example.

```
use [databasename]
go
create procedure [dbo].[my_stored_procedure](@customerid int) as
begin
insert into [customerstable](customerid) values (@customerid)
insert into [someothertable](somefieldname1, somefieldname2) values(somefield1value, somefield2value)
insert into [someothertable2](somefieldname1, somefieldname2) values(somefield1value, somefield2value)

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply how to get the input for 1 customerid 30 records of field1 and field2 for table someothertable.

Comment: well i myself send them as a single value and separate them in the sp. for example if I have to send some numbers i would send : "532,545,2365,868,233556,24232" and then separate them by commas. you will need to check character by character in a while statement to separate them.